# How to add new object in a json file using RobotFrameWork

Tags: json, robotframework

I am trying to add a new bloc to my JSON 
I have this JSON that I got after a GET : 

`{
    "name": "John",
    "age": 30,
    "Deleted": false
}`

What I want to do is to add a block trips to this Json using RobotFrameWOrk to get this result:

```
{
"name": "John",
"age": 30,
"trips": [
    {
        "dateTime": "2020-01-24T15:28:29.7073727Z",
        "FirstName": "John",
        "Comment": "TestMe"
    }
],
"Deleted": false
```

}

My questions are: 
The object Trips doesn't exist I have to create it manually 
and then I should add this object to my JSON after the `age` and before `Deleted`

```
${JsonFinall}=     Add String    ${FirstJson}    ${BlockTrips}
```

Log    ${JsonFinall}

I imagine it would be something like that but I am blocked on the first step I don't know how to create and fill the object trips? 
Do you think that I have to work with Regex? 
Thanks for your help 
***********************EDIT********** 
I tried with add object to json : `# Bloc ActionR

${jsonFinall}=     Add Object To Json    ${JsonAvecAR}    Course/AR.txt`

the file AR.txt is the file where I put my object trips :

```
"trips": [
    {
        "dateTime": "2020-01-24T15:28:29.7073727Z",
        "FirstName": "Alicia",
        "Comment": "TestMe"
    }
],[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: [JSONLibrary](https://github.com/robotframework-thailand/robotframework-jsonlibrary) has this functionality and it is documented.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply, I will edit my question with the code I wrote with library you mentioned, would you take a look, please?

Comment: KEYWORD ${jsonFinnal}= = Add Object To Json ${JsonAvecAR}, Course/AR.txt
Start / End / Elapsed: 20200206 15:25:47.370 / 20200206 15:25:47.371 / 00:00:00.001
15:25:47.371 FAIL No keyword with name 'Add Object To Json' found

Comment: Did you import the library in `*** Settings ***` section: `Library    JSONLibrary`?

Comment: I don't work an IDE I use Squash and with Squash and I don't know how to do that with Squash , I thought that I have all the libraries

Comment: Hello I have added the jsonLibrary and I was able to create a dictionary trips with the following line:  `${trips}=    Create Dictionary       datetime= ${dateHeureRealisation}    FirstName= Jhon       comment= Test`
but to add this block to my previous Json I can't make it work I used:  add Object to Json but I see no changement I don't see the block in the json